# Syncing Data with Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to set up a pipeline in Azure Data Factory that performs a `MERGE` between the source and the destination rather than an `INSERT`?  I have been able to successfully select data from my source on-prem table and insert into my destination, but I'd really like to set up a pipeline that will continually update my destination with any changes in the source.  E.g copying new records that are added to the source, or updating any data which changes on an existing record.

I've seen references to the Data Sync framework, but from what I can tell that is only supported in the legacy portal.  My V12 databases do not even show up in the class Azure portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Stored Proc activity](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/data-factory-stored-proc-activity/) which could handle this.  You could use Data Factory to land the data in a staging table then call the stored proc to perform the `MERGE`.  Otherwise Data Factory logic is not that sophisticated so you could not perform a merge in the same way you could in SSIS for example.  Custom activities are probably not suitable for this, IMHO.  This is also in line with Data Factory being ELT rather than ETL.